# SSIS Build a variable string that includes quotes (")

Tags: ssis

I am using SSIS Expression Builder to build a destination table name value for a Teradata OLEDB connector. Teradata is expecting the database (TSKAGGS) and the table (Cabinet_50) to be enclosed by double quotes (").  I am having trouble figuring out how to configure the variable.

So far, I have the current code:

**@[User::strDestDB]+"."+ @[User::strDestTable] +  @[User::strSource_ID]**

Returns: **TSKAGGS.Cabinet_50**

I need it to return: **"TSKAGGS"."Cabinet_50"**

How do I add the double quote character to my result?

Answer (score 20):

You need to escape the inner quote with a `\`

```
"abc" + "\"in quotes\""
```

[image]

Your specific replace would be

```
"\"" + @[User::strDestDB] + " \".\""+ @[User::strDestTable] + @[User::strSource_ID] + "\""
```

Or, you can be lazy and define a Variable called DoubleQuote and simply make the above

```
@[User::DoubleQuote] + @[User::strDestDB] + @[User::DoubleQuote] 
+ "." + @[User::DoubleQuote] + @[User::strDestTable] 
+ @[User::strSource_ID] + @[User::DoubleQuote]
```

Comment: Ahh! The elusive escape character.  Perfect.

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out.  I created another variable named strQuote and assigned " as the value.
Next, I modified the expression to;

**@[User::strQuote] + @[User::strDestDB]+ @[User::strQuote]+ "."+ @[User::strQuote]+ @[User::strDestTable] +  @[User::strSource_ID]+  @[User::strQuote]**

The result returns: **"TSKAGGS"."Cabinet_50"**

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the expression in variable to the sql query and calling that variable in Execute SQl task,please look at query for your question.

`LEFT(@[User::FileName],3)=="PWR" ? " SELECT * FROM  "+ "["+@[User::SheetName]+"A36:T]" : "SELECT * FROM  "+ "["+@[User::SheetName]+"A35:T]"`

Result will be `" SELECT * FROM  [report$A36:T]"`